Feast: permission denied for schema registry
I am running feast server with the following feature_store.yaml config
project: Myproj
provider: local
registry:
  registry_type: sql
  path: <MY_POSTGRES_URL>
online_store:
  type: postgres
  host: <MY_HOST>
  port: <MY_PORT>
  database: <MY_DB_NAME>
  db_schema: fs_online
  user: <MY_USER>
  password: <MY_PASSWORD>

I have an error:
Feast is an open source project that collects anonymized error reporting and usage statistics. To opt out or learn more see https://docs.feast.dev/reference/usage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for schema registry
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE entities (
                     ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app-root/bin/feast", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/feast/cli.py", line 715, in serve_command
    store = FeatureStore(repo_path=str(repo), fs_yaml_file=fs_yaml_file)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/feast/usage.py", line 362, in wrapper
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/feast/usage.py", line 348, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/feast/feature_store.py", line 169, in __init__
    self._registry = SqlRegistry(registry_config, None)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/feast/infra/registry/sql.py", line 197, in __init__
    metadata.create_all(self.engine)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4785, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3117, in _run_ddl_visitor
    conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2113, in _run_ddl_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 524, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 849, in visit_metadata
    self.traverse_single(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 524, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 893, in visit_table
    self.connection.execute(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1289, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 80, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1381, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1845, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2026, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for schema registry
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE entities (

I have db schema "public"
Why does feast trying to use schema "registry"?
